# Symfony2 password encoder function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, password-encryption, cryptojs

I created a Symfony2 application using FOSUserBundle and FOSRestBundle. I'd like to connect other application with my Symfony application using rest api. 
I need to write the Symfony password encoder function in Javascript.
Actually in PHP, it goes like:

```
$salt = "secret";
$password = "azerty";
$salted = $password.'{'.$salt.'}';
$digest = hash('sha512', $salted, true);

for ($i = 1; $i < 5000; $i++) {
    $digest = hash('sha512', $digest.$salted, true);
}
$digest = base64_encode($digest);

return $digest;
```

In Javascript, I tried to use CryptoJS library. My code is:

```
var salt = 'secret',
    password = 'azerty',
    salted = password + '{' + salt + '}'
    digest = CryptoJS.SHA512(salted);

for (var i=1; i<5000; i++) {
    digest = CryptoJS.SHA512(digest+salted);
}

digest = digest.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

return digest;
```

But guess what ? It does not work and i don't know why.
Can anyone help please ? :)

Regards,
Colzak.

Comment: What does `It does not work` mean?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I should have say, the digest returned are not the same.
PHP returns 
ZBNCDQnUk31GBE5y10AG5MUbEzsN9kNGmiORRMTss+DiwtDtRaFJwjoMJQFp7mMTfgvrm8GrUx0q87hmYNYihw==
And Javascript returns
q2lsiVES6m+Bxmzz87jk5z8epHE+jcd8tfIcIBWVx3KBuke+F9HuaahTHkhvqJDNASxw5mFEWgc2eng44Z8yKA==

Comment: @Colzak: What are you actually trying to accomplish? That looks really frightening.

Comment: @lxg I wanted to copy the password encode function of Symfony to avoid sending the user's password through the api call. On the client side, I get the user's password salt only, so when he type his password, I generate the corresponding hash, which is sent to the server and compared to the one in db. By doing this, the password is never transmitted through the api calls.

Comment: Anyway, I guess there is no solution to this problem. In other language (like java) I saw a working example but in Javascript it's a bit more complex I guess. Maybe instead of doing this, I could just base64_encode the password and send it through https... idk.

Comment: Well, it's none of my business, but I would recommend an approach based on a one-time token. Or use OAuth.

Comment: Either the token/oauth solution as @lxg suggested or see if that api support `SSL`/`TLS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok @timothymctim 's response helped me. Actually, I think it's an issue about character encoding.
Here's a (strange) solution :

The PHP:

```
$salt = "secret";
$password = "azerty";
$salted = $password.'{'.$salt.'}';
$digest = hash('sha512', $salted, true);

for ($i = 1; $i < 5000; $i++) {
    $digest = hash('sha512', utf8_encode($digest).$salted, true);
}
$digest = base64_encode($digest);

return $digest;
```

And the Javascript :

```
var salt = 'secret',
password = 'azerty',
salted = password + '{' + salt + '}'
digest = CryptoJS.SHA512(salted);

for (var i=1; i<5000; i++) {
    digest = CryptoJS.SHA512(digest.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1)+salted);
}

digest = digest.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

return digest;
```

I don't know what to think.
Thanks anyway everybody who helped !

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because "[t]he hash you get back isn't a string yet. It's a WordArray object. When you use a WordArray object in a string context, it's automatically converted to a hex string." ([source](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Hasher_Output))
By using `digest = CryptoJS.SHA512(digest+salted);` digest is converted into a hex string.
If you change your PHP code to

```
$salt = "secret";
$password = "azerty";
$salted = $password.'{'.$salt.'}';
$digest = hash('sha512', $salted, false);

for ($i = 1; $i < 5000; $i++) {
    $digest = hash('sha512', $digest.$salted, false);
}

return $digest;
```

and return the digest as a hex string (`digest + ''` or `digest.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)` will do) it will work.
I'm not sure how to change the JavaScript code to match the original PHP code though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got what you meant, but unfortunately, I need to let the php function as it is. I don't know if any solution exists. I'll try few more things, but I guess I will have to do another way.